# use of void *ptr and int fd in epoll data structure at same time

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, tcp, epoll

I am using the `epoll` system call for handling more than one client in TCP conversation.

I have registered `epoll` with fd:

```
epoll_ctl (efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &event);
```

and able to use with comparing fd as:

```
if(conn->getSockfd() == events[i].data.fd)
    // ....
```

But as epoll data structure

```
typedef union epoll_data {
    void    *ptr;
    int      fd;
    uint32_t u32;
    uint64_t u64;
} epoll_data_t;
```

I want to map a object(function) to particular `fd` field, so I can call this function after comparison.

But I am not getting correct result. It is possible to do or not? If yes then I can use it?

Comment: How are you doing it now?

Comment: currently I am able to compare `fd` of particular client. I want to map a object with the particular `fd`. So suppose I have 5 connections each connection will have different object. So I can call the correct object for every `fd` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a union for your epoll_data_t. So it can only store one of the fields a time. So either your void*, int, whatever.

I noticed you tagged your question with C++ so here's I would approach the problem:

You can tie a descriptor and function together in a class/struct and then create a new instance of it for every connection you accept/create. During construction you can then pass the FD and the function into your new object.

Here's a quick and untested concept of it:

```
template < typename FunctionType >
struct Connection
{
    int FD;
    std::function< FunctionType >   DoStuff;

    Connection( int descriptor, const std::function< FunctionType >& Func )
      : FD      ( descriptor )
      , DoStuff ( Func )
}
```

You can then call the constructor, pass it your file descriptor and the function to execute with a std::bind and then call it by doing Connection.DoStuff().

You can go wild with parameters and such if you use placeholders and the like. For more info on [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) follow the hyperlinks.